# Implementing max amount of time for user input through buttons in python/raspberry pi

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I'm struggling to find a way to implement a timelimit in the nested while-loop. I want the user to have a set amount of time to press the button(15 seconds for example). The program should break out of the nested loop once a maximum of three presses has been reached(which works) or once the timelimit has been surpassed. This is a piece of code for an autonomoust RC car. Thanks in advance.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

button1 = 26

GPIO.setup(button1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
print("Where do you want to go? Press once to go to the right, twice to go left or three times to go straight"
      "Wait one second inbetween clicks and 10 seconds to finish the process.")
while 1:
    clickCounter = 0
    while 1:  # Keeps track of clicks.
        if GPIO.input(button1) == 0:
            clickCounter += 1
            print("Amount of clicks: ", clickCounter)
            time.sleep(1)
        if clickCounter == 3 or x:  # Loop breaks if amount of clicks is 3 or if the time is up.
            break
    # Different outcomes based on the amount of clicks.
    if clickCounter == 0:
        print("Press the button 1-3 times.")
    elif clickCounter == 1:
        print("We're going to the right.")
        clickCounter = 0
        break
    elif clickCounter == 2:
        print("We're going to the left.")
        clickCounter = 0
        break
    elif clickCounter == 3:
        print("We're going straight.")
        clickCounter = 0
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate elapsed time (from the start of the loop) and exit the loop when time is up.

```
while 1:
    # Mark time at start of loop
    start_time = time.time()
    clickCounter = 0
    while 1:  # Keeps track of clicks.
        if GPIO.input(button1) == 0:
            clickCounter += 1
            print("Amount of clicks: ", clickCounter)
            time.sleep(1)      # I assume this is here for debounce
        # Calc time since start of loop
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if clickCounter == 3 or elapsed_time >= 15:  # Loop breaks if amount of clicks is 3 or if the time is up.
            break
    # Different outcomes based on the amount of clicks.
    ....
```